# Nuxt.js: page transitions

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

In my nuxt.config.js I added `loading: '~/components/LoadingBar.vue'`.

After deploying the site my custom page transition works, but only when the first page visited is different from the `home` page.

For example, if you visit this link and navigate from there to `/About`, or `/Portfolio`, you'll see my custom transition (blur effect + loading circle).

Now, click on the logo (my name, above the "Home" menu item): my custom page transition inexplicably resets to default Nuxt page transition, with the white loading bar at the very top of the page.

Not sure if that's a known bug with `Nuxt.js`, I can't think of anything in my code that could cause something like that. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page reloads once you click on the logo,
it seems you are using a simple <a> link instead of <nuxt-link>.

Set a name like this for your home route in `router.js`

```
{
    name: 'home',
    path: '/',
    component: Index
}
```

then `<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'home' }">logo</nuxt-link>`